# Blinks or flash bgcolor

Tags: javascript, css, colors, html-table

I have there is a table showing the last 10 news. But when I want to put any new command to the news appears in the td blinks or flash bgcolor.

Comment: I think you will need to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **jQuery**, you can achieve this effect with `animate` like this:

```
$(".my-new-tr td").css("background:#ffff00")             // make the background yellow
                  .animate({ "background": "#ffffff" })  // fade to white
                  .parent().removeClass("my-new-tr");
```

This assumes your newly added row will be given the class `my-new-tr` when created. This class will be removed after the effect.